# Question on workaround to parse_xml truncating zeros in the end

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per snowflake documentation -
If the content of an XML element is a number with digits after the decimal point, then PARSE_XML might truncate trailing zeros.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_xml.html

We need to know how can we avoid this truncation, is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: Do you have an example XML source and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

so making some data to see this

```
select 
    parse_xml(column1) as v,
    GET(v, '@attr') as attr
  from values
    ('<a attr="123">text</a>'),
    ('<a attr="223.00">text</a>'),
    ('<a attr="323.30">text</a>'),
    ('<a attr="423.04">text</a>');
```

gives:

| V | ATTR |
| --- | --- |
| text | 123 |
| text | 223 |
| text | 323.3 |
| text | 423.04 |

so it's true, the 'zeros' are going, but to another degree they also where not there.

so adding another column that we just turn to number

```
select 
    parse_xml(column1) as v
    ,GET(v, '@attr')::float as attr
    ,column2::float 
  from values
    ('<a attr="123">text</a>',123),
    ('<a attr="223.00">text</a>',223.00),
    ('<a attr="323.30">text</a>',323.30),
    ('<a attr="423.04">text</a>',423.04 );
```

| V | ATTR | COLUMN2::FLOAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | 123 | 123 |
| text | 223 | 223 |
| text | 323.3 | 323.3 |
| text | 423.04 | 423.04 |

so it's not so much that the "zero's are truncated" as if it looks like a number, it's treated like a number, and floating point numbers don't need trailing zeros.

so the solution is to turn the number back to text, and put the zero's back to the desired level:

```
select 
    parse_xml(column1) as v
    ,GET(v, '@attr')::float as attr
    ,to_char(attr,'999.0000') as attr_char
    ,column2::float 
    ,to_char(column2::float ,'999.0000') as float_char
  from values
    ('<a attr="123">text</a>',123),
    ('<a attr="223.00">text</a>',223.00),
    ('<a attr="323.30">text</a>',323.30),
    ('<a attr="423.04">text</a>',423.04 );
```

gives:

| V | ATTR | ATTR_CHAR | COLUMN2::FLOAT | FLOAT_CHAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text | 123 | 123.0000 | 123 | 123.0000 |
| text | 223 | 223.0000 | 223 | 223.0000 |
| text | 323.3 | 323.3000 | 323.3 | 323.3000 |
| text | 423.04 | 423.0400 | 423.04 | 423.0400 |

Comment: Thanks for the response, but for us to be able to "put the zero's back to the desired level:" , we need to know the desired level in the data which will not always be possible. Please advise.

Comment: so you have a string that you want to keep a string, because I show if you convert it in the DB to a number you lose you string ness of it. And the XML implementation auto converts to numbers, so ether don't use XML (I highly suggest this one, JSON is so much more functional) or add a non-numeric token to the start of your "number strings" and strip it off later.